# Using Cordova Plugin in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova for create an App in Android and iOS, in iOS I did not have any problem, and the app is now in the App Store.

I have some questions for Android, because I am desperate...

I created the Project using `cordova platform add android`, and the project created fine. I can load and compile, and all works fine, except the plugins... I have added the plugins correctly and works fine in iOS using the command `cordova plugins add org.cordova...`

Can someone tell me how I need to use the plugins in Android? Do I need include any .js (of course Cordova.js is include, but I don't know how exactly is my project using it, like a charm...).

I just can see an error in LogCat that say:

```
error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.inappbrowse
```

The app works, but the alerts is showing the typical alert of a browser and the links is open inside my App, I use it with this code:

```
$('a[target=_blank]').on('click', function(e) {
                             e.preventDefault();
                             window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_system');
                             return false;
                         });
```

And for the notifications:

```
navigator.notification.alert("Hello!", null, "Title", "Close");
```

Can someone show me a way to solve the problem? An example?

Just for information... I have tried this very simple example ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422346/notification-alert-is-not-working-in-phonegap-build-3-1-0?answertab=active#tab-top)) in a new separate project and App and I have the some error... Maybe the error is in the Config.xml? How I need to use it for Android?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: there might be a **plugin** folder in root of your project, inside it would be **android** folder. see what plugins are properly added for android.also check all plugins added using `cordova plugin ls`

Comment: Hi @turtle, everything is ok, but it's not working...

org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.11 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.10 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.3 "InAppBrowser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall all plugins and reinstalling them again solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run it and watch console.  If you get a "Refused to execute inline event handler" type message then add 'unsafe-inline' to your default source in the content security policy of your config.xml file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'   
data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 
'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self'; media-src *;">
```

Details on the policies are available at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy .

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa.